# adding a panel dynamically

Tags: asp.net

![how do I add a panel with an image control and a label dynamically (on button click)??][1]

i want this:

i select an image and press delete, it should delete (from the database) the image and the image name (label)... i press add and a new image control with a label should be added...

problem:

i cant seem to be able to select anything on the page...

what i have:
i have put the image and the label in a panel.. i delete the panel and it gets deleted... however, since the PANEL is not stored in the database, it only gets deleted temporarily.. it comes back the next time... what should i do to achieve what i want here..?

i have taken a repeater control & put a panel with an image & label inside it (i will have multiple similar panels in the repeater)... now how do i delete a particular panel from it...??

Comment: Can you post the code that generate the panel and image?

Comment: Dim p1 As Panel = New Panel
        Me.Controls.Add(p1)
        Dim l1 As Label = New Label
        ' Just only to test the working of panel control
        l1.Text = "abcd"
        Dim img As Image = New Image
        p1.Width = 200
        p1.Height = 200
        'p1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        'p1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        p1.Controls.Add(l1)
        p1.Visible = True
        p1.Enabled = True

Comment: Use repeater control to display panels with images, it will show panels for images based on number of rows returned.

Comment: In Visual Studio check your toolbox on left or refer [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx)

Comment: @AdityaNawandar, It should be under Data Tab in Toolbox if you are actually developing a asp.net site. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498210.aspx) link for screenshot

Comment: now what should i bind this to? how do i display panels with images in the repeater??